# Problems in initializing Spark session in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Context:

- Python 3.7 on jupyter lab 2.2.6
- Spark 2.4.7
- Windows 7 Professional
- Java 1.8.0

Try to run the following code:

```
   spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("test1") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "6gb") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-724444ec4271> in <module>
      2     .master("local[*]") \
      3     .appName("test1") \
----> 4     .config("spark.executor.memory", "6gb") \
      5     .getOrCreate()

~\Desktop\CATTOLICA\Approfondimenti\Python\SPARK\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    172                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 173                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    174                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    175                     for key, value in self._options.items():

~\Desktop\CATTOLICA\Approfondimenti\Python\SPARK\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    365         with SparkContext._lock:
    366             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 367                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    368             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    369 

~\Desktop\CATTOLICA\Approfondimenti\Python\SPARK\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    131                     " note this option will be removed in Spark 3.0")
    132 
--> 133         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    134         try:
    135             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

~\Desktop\CATTOLICA\Approfondimenti\Python\SPARK\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    314         with SparkContext._lock:
    315             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 316                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    317                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    318 

~\Desktop\CATTOLICA\Approfondimenti\Python\SPARK\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     44     :return: a JVM gateway
     45     """
---> 46     return _launch_gateway(conf)
     47 
     48 

~\Desktop\CATTOLICA\Approfondimenti\Python\SPARK\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py in _launch_gateway(conf, insecure)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

**Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number**
```

All the needed libraries have been imported and I also checked a lot of questions related to this type of error, but I'm not able to solve it. Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's always environment variables until you get it all figured it out. Let's say you're running ipython as your shell, here's all the settings you need to set to get spark working.

JAVA_HOME: This is the trickiest. In whatever shell or application you're running python from, `java --version` needs to be the version of java that you want to run. Python doesn't need java, but spark does. You can either set java home in the environment, or default it on the OS like I do.

```
(conda-common)thunder:common afraser$ java --version 
openjdk 13.0.1 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON: If you're using pyspark as a REPL, this doesn't matter. Definitely set this though and definitely use ipython from a terminal when setting up. Once you get this working, jupyter sits on top of ipython -- so if ipython works, jupyter (usually) will work also. Side note, conda makes this all this environment stuff really easy, way easier than trying to get everything working natively.

PYSPARK_PYTHON: This needs to be a pointer executable python you're using. I use both python 3.6 and 3.7, but most of the time this points to my python3.6 shortcut.

SPARK_HOME: You'll need to pip3 install pyspark to use pyspark in python, and be careful because you might already have spark installed somewhere setting up this variable. My spark home looks like this:  `SPARK_HOME=/Users/afraser/IdeaProjects/{redacted}/conda/env/{redacted}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark`

And in SPARK_HOME if you plan on using s3, you'll probably need three jars to match the version of pyspark you're running. These work.

```
thunder:jars afraser$ pwd
/Users/afraser/IdeaProjects/{redacted}/conda/env/{redacted}/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars
thunder:jars afraser$ ls -ltr |tail -3
-rw-r--r--  1 afraser  staff  11948376 Dec  1 15:00 aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 afraser  staff    126287 Dec  1 15:00 hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 afraser  staff     26012 Dec  1 15:00 hadoop-client-2.7.3.jar
```

Then you should be able to test in ipython. If you're using s3, make sure you have botocore pip installed, and the aws command line client set up so you can already run `aws s3 ls s3://{bucket}/{folder}` and see your stuff.

```
 thunder:{redacted} afraser$ ipython
 Python 3.7.7 (default, May 14 2020, 14:37:44)
 Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
 IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

 In [1]: import botocore.session
    ...: from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    ...: from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
    ...: session = botocore.session.get_session()
    ...: credentials = session.get_credentials()
    ...: spark = (
    ...:     SparkSession
    ...:         .builder
    ...:         .appName("my-application-executor")
    ...:         .getOrCreate()
    ...: )
 In [2]: df = spark.read.csv("s3a://{bucket}/{key}")
```

PYTHONPATH: Not related to the question above, but to keep this answer complete in nature, python path needs to have two things. 1) It needs to include your source tree, like {path}/src, plus, it needs to contain everything under {path}site-packages for the version of python you are running. (I have multiple so I double check).

Lastly, if you get all this stuff working, you might also want to quickly pip3 install aws wrangler and load stuff straight into pandas. If you do, remember if it's spark, it's s3a://, if it's wrangler or just about everything else, it's s3://.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a statistician so maybe I'm not so technical on computer science things... I can't understand where I should write the commands you suggest. Is there something I can do directly on Jupyter? Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, working with python is pretty easy, but adding spark on top of it is a definitely more tricky and usually requires knowing how all the environment variables are set up.  You can set an environment variable in jupyter like so ->  `import os; os.environ["myvar"] = "myvalue" `. Above are all the spark environment variables you need to configure. My guess is you might consider starting by making sure JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME are doing what you want.